# Blend UWP resolution/scale and effective resolution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, blend

I'm trying to build an uwp application for 8-inch tablet, and I'm confused with those terms **resolution/scale and effective resolution**, for example for the 8-inch tablet I have **1280x800 125% scale and the effective device resolution is 1024x640**
[image: blend screenshot]

Comment: Effective resolution * scale = resolution. The above screen shot is saying that your screen is 1280 x 800, but since everything is scaled 125%, your app will look about the same as if it were running on an unscaled 1024 x 640 screen.

Comment: @RaymondChen This is a perfect short answer. You should post this as an answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effective resolution * scale = resolution. The above screen shot is saying that your screen is 1280 x 800, but since everything is scaled 125%, your app will look about the same as if it were running on an unscaled 1024 x 640 screen.

Comment: thank you for the reply, so if i want my app to look well on a **8-inch 1280x800** i must design it in a 1024 x 640 screen ?, because in the mainpage.xaml i have the width=1024 and the height=800

Comment: @YMor You're overthinking it. If you want to look good on an 8-inch 1280x800 tablet, then set the designer to `8" tablet 1280x800`. The effective resolution is just telling you additional information about how this screen compares to other screens.